# Chrome Developer Tools Settings

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I have been using chrome dev tools for aligning various `<img>'s`. I was doing it by inspecting element and adding css into the auto generated selector by clicking the plus button in the style pane.

Somehow the auto generated css is not working same as before i.e is not generating css for a particular element e.g

Previously

```
#framebox_3920691 > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > a > img {
}
```

Now

```
img{
}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using such [extremely verbose] selectors is not recommended and is hardly maintainable. It's better to assign specific classes/ids to your images and use those in your selectors.

That said, if you definitely need the full CSS path for an element, right-click the element in the Elements panel and choose `Copy CSS Path` in the context menu to get the full CSS path into your system clipboard.

Comment: Thanks, can you answer another question? I have a css strike-through as seen in firebug but the override only takes place when i remove the tick mark with it manually. It is td rule defined for the whole page and i am trying to override its inheritance on other elements e.g `form#fclwishlist > div.framed_bottom > table > tbody > tr > td` but as seen in the styles pane my rule `form#fclwishlist { color: white !important; }` is pushed below the rule `body, td{color:black;}` but is working fine for the following element `form#fclwishlist > div.section_hdr`.

Comment: So, what is your question? Also, a live example would be immensely helpful